# Performing a simple join with the following

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

My slick and db access is setup like follows:

```
abstract class UserDao {
  def getById(id): Option[User]
}

class UserDaoImpl extends UserDao {
  class Users(....) extends Table[User](...) {
    def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    ..
    def * = (id, ...) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)
  }

  val users = TableQuery( new Users(..) )

  def getById(..) { .. }
}
```

Now suppose I have another class Articles, and a ArticleDao that looks like the above UserDao.

```
case class Article(id: Int, userId: Int, ..)
```

How could I perform an innerJoin query in slick like:

```
select * from users inner join users on users.id = articles.user_id
```

Please specify the imports for anything slick related as I get stuck on those also.

Answer (score 0):

Import your driver (the below assumes postgres). Check Slick docs for how to get a Database object.

```
import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._

val query = users.innerJoin(users).on(_.id === _.id)

val result: List[(User, User)] = db.withSession { implicit session =>
  query.run
}
```

This will return list of tuples